# no original function chain to wrap

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

What does this error mean?

I ran basic loopback application with `apic loopback emptyapp`

Then I added babel to use es6 and I get this error just before `server listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000`

Any advice on the error would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yay hat the same Problem. Seems `no original function chain to wrap` has no real impact but get rid of the message by updating my modules